# Generic Object that accepts only string key pair values in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

How do I convert this function to Typescript?

```
interface Attribute {
  src?: string;
  alt?: string;
  href?: string;
  title?: string;
  target?: string;
}

function setAttributes(element: HTMLElement, attributes: Attribute){
  for (const key in attributes) {
    element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]); // this part fails
  }
}
```

Here, `attributes[key]` fails to work. How can I work around this?

I have restructured the function like so:

```
function setAttributes(element: HTMLElement, attributes: Attribute) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(attributes as Record<string, string>)) {
    element.setAttribute(key, value);
  }
}
```

But Typescript throws an error for `Object.entries` saying

```
Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'
```

Comment: The entries error happens if you do not have the correct `libs` configured. The type definition appears to be in `lib.es2017.object.d.ts`, something above `ES2017` should probably do it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually i just use a `keyof` type assertion in that case:

```
function setAttributes(element: HTMLElement, attributes: Attribute) {
  for (const key in attributes) {
    const value = attributes[key as keyof Attribute];

    // still might error, because value could be undefined
    element.setAttribute(key, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This indeed does error if you have a single property in `Attribute` that's not a `string`, a workaround is to provide a default or do a check prior to caling `setAttribute()`

Comment: @MikeS.: The problem is not that a property could not be string, they all are, but they are all optional so the type will be `string | undefined` (even though the key will not show up in the loop if it is really missing).

Comment: Sorry I worded that poorly. I was implying that it's not a string if it's string | undefined, or any other type/type union

Answer (score 0):

This snippet actually works once I added `"ES2017"` to the `tsconfig`'s `lib`

*current working snippet*

```
function setAttributes(element: HTMLElement, attributes: Attribute) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(attributes as Record<string, string>)) {
    element.setAttribute(key, value);
  }
}
```